# Problem with dynamic casting

Tags: c++

This code returns me an error whenever I try to run this code. Can some one please help me.

```
struct m
{
    virtual int s( )
    { 
        return 1;
    }
};

struct n : public m
{
    int s( )
    { 
        return 2;
    }
};

int o( )
{
    n* p=new m;
    m* q=dynamic_cast<p>;
    return q->s( );
}
```

Comment: You should post what error you get when you run the code.

Comment: Write code like this if you wanna be the next kalashnikovs-break-down-employee victim nr 1.
Why on earth would you need dynamic_cast here?

Comment: You certainly don't need a `dynamic_cast` to call a virtual function. That's the whole point of virtual functions. And always check that the cast succeeded before you dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These C++ cast operators should be used as

```
dynamic_cast<newType>(variable)
```

In your case,

```
m* q = dynamic_cast<m*>(p);
```

BTW, are you confusing the role of `m` and `n`? `n* p = new m` is a syntax error because a base class instance cannot be implicitly converted to a derived class instance. In fact, base → derived *is* the situation where you actually need `dynamic_cast`, not the other way around (no casting is needed).

Also, consider giving meaningful names to objects.

Answer (score 2):

Next time, please tell us what the error is!

I suppose you're saying that there is a compile error because you're not using dynamic_cast right? You probably meant to say

```
m* q=dynamic_cast<m *>(p);
```

In general, dynamic_cast is the devil. Most implementations are insanely slow and might go as far as going string-based class name checks. Unless you really, absolutely need to use dynamic_cast, please use any other method available (such as static_cast).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm has the best of both casts..

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, first you can't allocate an m and call it n in the first line of main.  You have a syntatic error in the dynamic_cast.  It is `dynamic_cast<new type>(some var)`.